# What type of data record with the annotation @ Lob with JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lob

I have a problem, When I'm recording a PDF file inside the bank, I better save as file or byte []?

```
@Lob @Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name="arqdocumento")
private File arquivo;
```

or

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Column(name="arqdocumento")
private byte[] arquivo;
```

And how do I get this file from database and display in the browser?

I wonder why I do it this way:

```
public File getDocumentoBinary(int iDdocumento){
   Query consulta = getSesseion().createSQLQuery("SELECT arqdocumento FROM documento WHERE iddocumento = :id");
   consulta.setInteger("id", iDdocumento);
   return  (File) consulta.uniqueResult();     }
```

but displays this error:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -4

Answer (score 2):

```
@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
@Column(name="arqdocumento")  
private byte[] arquivo;
```

is the correct approach to store the huge amount of data in the DB. Your error says you have to include the Dialect in the persistence.xml file. So verify you have entered the correct Dialect property.

Comment: Thanks Everybody, but this error I think that´s something with  with the query, exist another way for search this file in database with the Criteria API or other way? I´m using org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect.

Comment: I found the solution, the query is certain what was causing the error was the component p: commandButton inside a p: dialog.Então changed the button to h: commandButton and no longer had the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use a byte array, or InputStream, or a SQL blob type. You cannot map a blob column to a File.